# Use tmux pane-border-format with vim to set pane titles

Tags: vim, tmux

Inside my `init.vim` I have some code like this to set my window titles:

```
augroup Tmux "{{{2
  au!
  autocmd VimEnter,BufNewFile,BufReadPost * call system('tmux pane-border-format "#{pane_index} vim-' . split(substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', ''), '/')[-1] . '"')
  " autocmd VimLeave * call system('tmux pane-border-format "#{pane_index} ' . split(substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', ''), '/')[-1] '"')

  autocmd VimEnter,BufNewFile,BufReadPost * call system('tmux rename-window "vim-' . split(substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', ''), '/')[-1] . '"')
  autocmd VimLeave * call system('tmux rename-window ' . split(substitute(getcwd(), $HOME, '~', ''), '/')[-1])
augroup END
```

Those lines with `pane-border-format` are me trying to get that to work right. the `rename-window` stuff works fine right now.

I already have `set -g pane-border-status bottom` set in my `.tmux.conf` and I can see the pane titles showing up, but they're not changing when I start vim.

Right now the `pane-border-format` stuff isn't doing anything. Am I close to getting this to work the way I want? Can anyone give me some code that will set the tmux pane text to do the same stuff as my window titles?

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way to do this [in the tmux issue tracker](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/564). It's just a matter of having this in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g pane-border-format " #P: #{pane_current_command} "
```

No need to set up anything in my vim files!